# How can I call a program from a bash script with arguments and then write to that program's stdin

Tags: bash

I have a program that takes two sets of arguments. The first set when it's called, and then a second set from the standard input.

I want to write a shell script which will call the program with the first set of arguments on the command line and then pass the second set to the running program via its stdin.

I don't know how to do the second part when the shell script is waiting for input on stdin. Should I just `echo` the second set of arguments from the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can send input to STDIN of a program with `<<<`. Just append it after the command line arguments.

```
$ perl -E 'say @ARGV; say <STDIN>' foo <<<'bar'
foo
bar
```

This is not related to Perl, but rather is a feature of bash (and other shells).